# JavaScript - Check which child string occurs first in a parent string using string.indexOf()

Tags: javascript

I have a really long "parent" string (about 2,000 characters).
I want to find out which of two "child" strings (or substrings) occur first.
So far I've been using `string.indexOf()`:

```js
/* VARIABLES */
var parentString = "Lorem foo ipsum dolor sit bar amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,..."

var firstSubstring = "foo"
var secondSubstring = "bar"

var firstSubstringLength = firstSubstring.length
var secondSubstringLength = secondSubstring.length

var searchIndex = 0
var continuationIndex = 0

/* SEARCH FOR SUBSTRINGS */

// Check if the substring exists
if (parentString.indexOf(firstSubstring, searchIndex) > -1) {
  console.log("firstSubstring occurred first in the ParentString")
  // Make the compiler continue its search from the end of firstSubstring"
  searchIndex = parentString.indexOf(firstSubstring, continuationIndex)
  continuationIndex = searchIndex + firstSubstringLength
}
// Check if the substring exists
if (parentString.indexOf(secondSubstring, searchIndex) > -1) {
  console.log("secondSubstring occurred second in the ParentString")
  // Make the compiler continue its search from the end of secondSubstring"
  searchIndex = parentString.indexOf(secondSubstring, continuationIndex)
  continuationIndex = searchIndex + secondSubstringLength
}
```

In a scenario where `secondSubstring` occurred in the `parentString` first, this code would still output that `firstSubstring` occurred first (because of the way this code is structured).
Is there a way to scan for both variables simultaneously and return the one which occurs first?.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing that the first substring is first whenever the first substring is found, before comparing to the position of the second substring.

Use `indexOf()` for each of them, and then just compare their indexes.

```js
/* VARIABLES */
var parentString = "Lorem foo ipsum dolor sit bar amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,..."

var firstSubstring = "foo"
var secondSubstring = "bar"

var firstSubstringLength = firstSubstring.length

/* SEARCH FOR SUBSTRINGS */

var firstIndex = parentString.indexOf(firstSubstring);
var secondIndex = parentString.indexOf(secondSubstring);

if (firstIndex > -1 && secondIndex > -1) {
  if (secondIndex >= firstIndex + firstSubstringLength) {
    console.log("secondSubstring occurred second in the ParentString");
  } else {
    console.log("secondSubstring did not occur second in the ParentString");
  }
} else if (firstIndex == -1) {
  console.log("firstSubstring was not found in the ParentString");
} else {
  console.log("secondSubstring was not found in the ParentString");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex replacement to measure the position of first occurrence of each substring:

```js
var parentString = "Lorem foo ipsum dolor sit bar amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,...";
var foo_index = parentString.replace(/^(.*?)foo\b.*$/, "$1").length;
var bar_index = parentString.replace(/^(.*?)bar\b.*$/, "$1").length;
if (foo_index < bar_index) {
    console.log("foo occurs first");
}
else {
    console.log("bar occurs first");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it can help you,

```
var parentString = "Lorem foo ipsum dolor sit bar amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,..."

var firstSubstring = "foo"
var secondSubstring = "bar"

var firstStringIndex = parentString.indexOf(firstSubstring);
var secondStringIndex = parentString.indexOf(secondSubstring);

firstStringIndex>secondStringIndex ? console.log(secondStringIndex) : console.log(firstStringIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

While I believe the best answer has already been posted, another option would be to use positive lookahead regular expressions (though, in this case, they may prove slightly more computationally expensive -- but, might provide for more terse code -- verbosity is NOT a bad thing however, so I'd still stick with the indexOf).

For example,

```
const ss1index = parentString.indexOf(substring1);
const ss2index = parentString.indexOf(substring2);

const retest = new RegExp(substring1 +'(?='+ substring2 +')');
const ss1test = retest.test(parentString);

if (ss1index > -1) {
  if (ss2index > -1) {
  // substring 1 and 2 were both found in parent
    // You could rewrite the logic so you actually store the indexOf value if you need it.
    if (ss1test) // substring1 is first
    else substring2 is first
  }
}
```